# Why we can't run the Visual Basic Application on Mac?

Tags: macos, vb6

Why we can't Run the VB6 applications in Mac OS? I know Mac doesn't have VB runtime, Could anyone explain about this further?

Comment: @Remou: You changed my edit? The user mentioned `VB6 applications in Mac OS` I hope you are aware that vb6 and VBA are different?

Comment: You can't use VB6 to run natively on a MAC but you can use RealBasic which is a cross-platform product very much like VB6.

Comment: I think that the question needs clarification. Many people mistakenly say VB6 when they mean VBA. The user chose VBA for the tag, so perhaps that is what they meant.

Comment: VBA application do run on MAC at least Office 2011 onwards

Comment: So why not provide that answer rather than changing the tags to make the question work for you? The OP included a VBA tag, so I do not think it is right to simply overrule them without some clarification as to where the error lies.

Comment: I didn't change the Tag so that the question "Works" for me. It's called Common Sense...

Comment: Not to intentionally be mean, but I don't understand how this is a programming question.

Answer (score 6):

As you say, there is no VB6 runtime for the MAC - given VB6 relies heavily on COM and Mac OS is a unix-like OS I can see why it would be hard to port (though not [impossible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260790%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)) - the control library would have to be different too, since the UI on the platforms is quite different in places.  I suspect fundamentally that the effort vs benefit was never high enough to get it done, but that is just conjecture.  As MS have dropped support for VB6 on Windows some time ago, I wouldn't hold out any hope of it appearing on the Mac from them now.

There is a VB-like tool from Real Software called [Real Studio](http://www.realsoftware.com/realstudio/vbdevelopers.php) that works on Mac apparently so if the reason for the question is that you have VB6 skills and are looking to develop for the Mac platform, that might be a possible solution.

And, since you tagged with VBA...VBA is available in the MS Office 2011 products though you will, possibly, have to go about things slightly differently on the two platforms (you can call applescript from VBA in Excel on the MAC).

Comment: There is also a *very much more* VB6-like language and toolset called Jabaco which is free in its current form and based on Java so it has pretty good portability.